# Creating a identifier between a UIImage and the image of a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I'm making a game that a character will have a ballon thought and a bunch of buttons above. Every five seconds, the image of the ballon will change, so as the organization of the buttons.

I manage to create the code to make the sort of the images, but I'm having a difficult to create the logic to link the button to the ballon. The idea is when the new image of the ballon is showed, the user must click the button that correspond to the image.

Here a picture to illustrate better:

[image]

I tried to do with Enums, but doesnt work for me. Here's my code:

```
enum PontuacaoJogo {

    case toddynho
    case coxinha
    case sushi
    case coracao
    case netflix


    case ballonToddynho
    case ballonCoxinha
    case ballonSushi
    case ballonCoracao
    case ballonNetflix

    var imagemNecessidades: UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .toddynho: return UIImage(named: "toddy_.png")!
        case .coxinha: return UIImage(named: "coxinha_.png")!
        case .sushi: return UIImage(named: "sushi_.png")!
        case .coracao: return UIImage(named: "coracao_.png")!
        case .netflix: return UIImage(named: "bedflix_1.png")!

        default: ()
        }
   return imagemNecessidades }

    var imagemBaloes: UIImage {

        switch self {
        case .ballonToddynho: return UIImage(named: "toddy_.png")!
        case .ballonCoxinha: return UIImage(named: "coxinha_.png")!
        case .ballonSushi: return UIImage(named: "sushi_.png")!
        case .ballonCoracao: return UIImage(named: "coracao_.png")!
        case .ballonNetflix: return UIImage(named: "bedflix_1.png")!

        default: ()
        }

   return imagemBaloes }


}
```

After that I tried to create a If else statement comparing the image of the `UIButton` with the image of the ballon, but I cant find something generic, like:

```
if imgBtn1.imageView.image == ballon.image {
    // makes point
}
```

Because the image of the button and the image of the ballon have different names. So, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two options: UIViews can have a tag, and thus you can tag your buttons with an enum ID. Without knowing how your app is setup some relevant parts would look similar to:

```
// Declare enums in some header
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PontuacaoJogo)
{
    PontuacaoJogoSushi,
    PontuacaoJogoNetflix
};

// When you create the thought bubble with the image needing to match
-(void)createThoughtBubble
{
   //logic to choose image
    self.thoughtBubbleID = PontuacaoJogoSushi;
    //self.someImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sushi"];
}


-(UIButton*)imagemBaloes:(PontuacaoJogo)buttonID
{
    UIButton* someButton;
    someButton.tag = buttonID;
}

//Tap delegate for the three buttons
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* buttonTapped = (UIButton*)sender; //if typeof class etc....
    if( buttonTapped.tag == self.thoughtBubbleID )
    {
        //Match
    }
}
```

The other would be to subclass UIButton and add properties for your enum if you are going to extend these buttons further; (Likely the case in most game productions).

```
@interface SimonSaysButton : UIButton
    @property (nonatomic) PontuacaoJogo imageID;
@end
```

Either way, I would not compare for image equality but rather test for the data, in your case an enumeration value.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to work:

The solution i used was to create two arrays, one for the ballon images and another for the button images. So, in the if else statements, i compare the index of the two arrays and worked!